# Python login script with encryption

Tags: python, authentication

So i recently wrote this script to make a login interface that then stores all the login details into an encrypted .data file in python but for some reason it always returns me an error. I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me?

```
import os
import hashlib

def encrypt_password(password):
    encrypted_password = hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()
    return encrypted_password

def create_account(username, password):
    encrypted_password = encrypt_password(password)


data_file = open(username + '.data', 'w')
data_file.write(username + '\n')
data_file.write(encrypted_password)
data.file.close()
print('Account successfully created!')

def login(username, password):
    encrypted_password = encrypt_password(password)

if os.path.exists(username + '.data'):
    data_file = open(username + '.data', 'r')
    stored_username = data_file.readline().rstrip('\n')
    stored_password = data_file.readline()

    if username == stored_username and encrypted_password == stored_password:
        print('Login successful!')
    else:
        print('Incorrect username or password')

else:
    print('Account does not exist. Please create an account first.')


user_input = input('Do you want to create (c) or login (l) to an account? ')


if user_input == 'c':
    username = input('Enter username: ')
    password = input('Enter password: ')
    create_account(username, password)


elif user_input == 'l':
    username = input('Enter username: ')
    password = input('Enter password: ')
    login(username, password)

else:
    print('Invalid input')
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsvxL.png)

it keeps returning me this error

Comment: Please fix code indentation

Comment: Code indentation error starting from line 
`data_file = open(username + '.data', 'w')` till
`print('Account successfully created!')`

Comment: I did that but still returns that error. username not defined

Comment: If you indeed fixed your indentation (which seems you did not update in the post), the problem is exactly what it says - that variable is not defined (no value was assigned to it). As other languages it sequentially reads the source code from 1 line and follows on second etc. When it arrives to `data_file = open(username + '.data', 'w')` there is no previous line where you create the `username` variable by `username = "joe"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day,

I saw the mistake. It is a very minor mistake and can be easily fixed. All you have to do is put your if..else.. statement at the top and move some of the code to their functions. Like this:

```
import os
import hashlib

def encrypt_password(password):
    encrypted_password = hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()
    return encrypted_password

def create_account(username, password):
    encrypted_password = encrypt_password(password)
    data_file = open(username + '.data', 'w')
    data_file.write(username + '\n')
    data_file.write(encrypted_password)
    data_file.close()
    print('Account successfully created!')

def login(username, password):
    global encrypted_password
    encrypted_password = encrypt_password(password)
    if os.path.exists(username + '.data'):
        data_file = open(username + '.data', 'r')
        stored_username = data_file.readline().rstrip('\n')
        stored_password = data_file.readline()

        if username == stored_username and encrypted_password == stored_password:
            print('Login successful!')
        else:
            print('Incorrect username or password')

    else:
        print('Account does not exist. Please create an account first.')

user_input = input('Do you want to create (c) or login (l) to an account? ')

if user_input == 'c':
    username = input('Enter username: ')
    password = input('Enter password: ')
    create_account(username, password)


elif user_input == 'l':
    username = input('Enter username: ')
    password = input('Enter password: ')
    login(username, password)

else:
    print('Invalid input')
```

I hope that this solves the problem :)